# Repost Swift: Displaying the vertices label properly on AR Face mesh

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to generate the face mesh from the AR face tutorial with proper vertices label using SCNText. I follow the online tutorial and have the following:

```
enterextension EmojiBlingViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,didUpdate node: SCNNode,for anchor: ARAnchor) {
  guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor,
    let faceGeometry = node.geometry as? ARSCNFaceGeometry else {
      return
  }
  faceGeometry.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)
}
  func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    guard let device = sceneView.device else {
      return nil
    }
    let faceGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device)
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: faceGeometry)
    for x in [1076, 1070, 1163] {
          let text = SCNText(string: "\(x)", extrusionDepth: 1)
          let txtnode = SCNNode(geometry: text)
          txtnode.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.001, y: 0.001, z: 0.001)
          txtnode.name = "\(x)"
          node.addChildNode(txtnode)
          txtnode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.fillMode = .fill
      }
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.fillMode = .lines
    return node
  }
}
```

However, those vertices (1076, 1070, 1163) not show properly- they are overlapped in the centre.

**So my question is, does anyone would know how to show (x in [1076, 1070, 1163]) properly in the correct location on the mesh?**

Thanks!

**Updates: I saw the numbers overlapped and they moved along with face**

Reference: [AR Face Tracking Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5491-ar-face-tracking-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started), [iOS ARKit Face Tracking Vertices](https://www.oxfordechoes.com/ios-arkit-face-tracking-vertices/)

**Edit: I am sorry that I repost here. I just hoped that more people could see the post and might give me a hand**

Comment: Anyone can help?

Comment: Anyone can help???

Comment: anyone please help me out...

Comment: Please help me out.......

Comment: Please help me out......

Comment: Please help me out.....

Comment: Please help me out......

Comment: Please help me out..

Comment: Please help me out......

Comment: Please help me out......

Comment: Please help out...........